# Php Remote access to Ec2 Mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, remote-access

Im trying to acess an EC2 mysql server from another EC2 instance using PHP.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('elastic_ip_host','user','pass','database');
if(!$con){
   echo mysqli_connect_error(); echo mysql_error();
}

//Also trying PDO
try
{
     $dbcon = new PDO('mysql:host=elastic_ip_host;dbname=database','user','pass');
    $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected!';
 }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   echo 'ERROR! '.$e->getMessage();
   die();
}
```

Can't connect to MySQL server on 'elastic_ip_host' (13)ERROR! SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'elastic_ip_host' (13)

Using MySQLWorkbench app in my computer, Im connecting pretty fine using Elastic IP (number).  Just PHP is not connecting.  Checking phpinfo I see it has pdo and mysqli all ok.

Do you have any idea?

(Also Im using percona and I run that command first install that ask if I will not be able to connect remotly with root. But I created a new user as %. Thats what I am using in MySqlWorkbench program from my computer to access the database fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running:

```
 setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

As root in ssh fixed my problem :)